# for loops in C++ and perfomance critical applications

Tags: c++

I am trying to write fast C++ code for performance critical applications, but my knowledge about compilers and compiler implementations is limited. I am currently working with the gcc compiler. Therefore, I'd like to know whether there is - in practice - a difference in performance between a for loop written as

```
//size is int argument

for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
    //code sequence C
}
```

and a for loop written as

```
//struct definition
struct s
{
    int size;

    //[...]
};

//[...]

//obj is reference of type s& (say)

for( int i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i )
{
    //code sequence C
}
```

where, of course, `size` and `obj.size` take on the same (LARGE!) `int` value. So the question is: In practice, does the lookup of `obj.size` take more time than the lookup of `size`. Would a code with a constant size variable even be faster? Does it depend on the code `C` (maybe the compiler determines whether the value of the size variable changes if `C` is simple enough...?!). So if the lookup of `obj.size` takes more time, would it be advisable to write

```
//obj is reference of type s& (say)

const int size = obj.size;

for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
    //code sequence C
}
```

or at least

```
//objs is std::vector<s> (say)

const int SIZE = objs.size();
int size;

for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i )
{
    size = objs[i].size;

    for( int j = 0; j < size; ++j )
    {
        //code sequence C
    }
}
```

if a more complex code example is assumed.

Comment: What you've surmised is all correct. Fetching obj.size will take more time than reading a simple size var. Putting size in a temp like you did will guarantee you don't keep dereferencing obj...BUT the optimizer will usually take care of this for you.

Comment: The answer is it depends on the compiler.  Compile it both ways and time how long it takes to do 100k iterations.  You have your answer.

Comment: It is best just to write the code that is maintainable and readable. When performance is an issue do some profiling. Remember the 80-20 rule

Comment: @Ed Heal: Couldn't agree more. This coding style only applies to a few VERY critical function calls in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very unlikely to be the bottleneck in your code. You can use a performance profiling tool like `perf` on Linux to determine where your CPU is spending the majority of its time.

In this case, the compiler can do the transformation you describe (Loop Invariant Code Motion) automatically if it can prove its correctness. In particular, the compiler needs to be sure that `obj.size` isn't modified inside the loop, so passing `obj` by reference or invoking a method on `obj` could cause the compiler to assume that `obj.size` might be modified, meaning it must be read every time.

In general, assume the compiler will do a good job optimizing your code, and go back and do micro-optimizations manually if profiling indicates it is important.

Comment: Don't trust invariant code motion too much, proving that a non-local value doesn't change through opaque calls done in the loop is often impossible, and even if s is local the compiler often just isn't smart enough. Manually moving the `size()` call out of the loop and taking the pointer to the first element at start when looping over e.g. an std::vector does yield measurable performance improvements in inner loops.

Comment: In this case it's a member variable, but yes, LICM is unlikely to be powerful enough for non-local values.